# Select box calling another element's click event jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a div on my page witch is hidden : AddSupplier, I have a button on my page witch must show the div if its not visible, but the same button saves some stuff if the div is visible. So all that is working but in this AddSupplier div there is a select box "ddSupplierTypes" and when the select box gets clicked the AddSupplierButton click event gets triggered why is this, and is there a work around?

Tanks for any help.

> <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
>
> ```
>     $().ready(function() {
>         $('#AddSupplier').hide();
>
>         $('[id$=AddSupplierButton]').click(function() {
>             if ($('#AddSupplier').is(':visible')) {
>                 //do this
>                 alert('event fired');
>             }
>             else {
>                 //do that
>                 $('#AddSupplier').show();
>
>             }
>
>             return false;
>         });
>     });
>
> </script> </head> <body>
> <form id="form1" runat="server">
> <div id="wrapper">
> <asp:ImageButton ID="AddSupplierButton" runat="server" Height="18px" 
> ImageUrl="~/images/add.png" 
> OnClientClick="return(false);"/>
> </div>
> <div id="AddSupplier">
>     <select id="ddSupplierTypes">
>     <option value="S">ss</option>
>     <option value="F">kk</option>
>     <option value="W">oo</option>
>     <option value="P">ii</option>
>     </select>
> </div>
> </form>
> ```

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown that on its own would cause the behavior you describe. Can you show your html, and the rest of your javascript code?

Comment: Sorry my bad.. updated my Question

Answer (score 0):

i suggest

```
if( $('#elemet').is(':visible') ) { do this }
   else { do that }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify the above code but forgot to mention that im working with master pages. So on my Master Page i got this image button control

`<asp:ImageButton ID="AddVerskaffer" OnClientClick="return(false);"/>`

witch i call in jQuery as  `'[id$=AddSupplierButton]'`   because the master page changes the control name to some long ID.

Any now I replaced the asp image button with a normal link

```
<a id="AddVerskaffer" href="javascript:void(0);"  ></a>
```

and now it works. No event gets fired when clicking on the select box.

Why do you think this happens?